# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure with use zxJDBC

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, plsql, jython

I took official example from http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html:

```
Oracle
>>> c = db.cursor() # open the database as in the examples above
>>> c.execute("create or replace function funcout (y out varchar2) return varchar2 is begin y := 'tested'; return 'returned'; end;")
>>> params = [None]
>>> c.callproc("funcout", params)
>>> print params
```

When I run this code I get exception:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCOUT'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

How to fix it?

Addition!!! Also does not work this code:

```
  outParam = ""
            self.cursor.execute("create or replace function funcout (y out varchar2) return varchar2 is begin y := 'tested'; return 'returned'; end;")
            self.cursor.callproc("funcout", [outParam])
```

Comment: Sorry I misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an OUT or IN OUT parameter, you must pass a variable, not a literal for that parameter. How else can the procedure pass the value back?

Comment: Can I get the example, please?

Comment: I don't understand how to call procedure with out parameter

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [PLSQLSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/BasicSamples/PLSQLSample.java)