# How to call procedure with use zxjdbc and get back OUT parameter?

Tags: plsql, jython, python-2.x

If I use official example from http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html

```
>>> c = db.cursor() # open the database as in the examples above
>>> c.execute("create or replace function funcout (y out varchar2) return varchar2 is begin y := 'tested'; return 'returned'; end;")
>>> params = [None]
>>> c.callproc("funcout", params)
>>> print params
['tested']
```

I get error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCOUT'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946480/wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-procedure-with-use-zxjdbc) have answer, but run the example with OUT parameter failed. Can you show an example that works with OUT parameter?